# Compartir noticia en Facebook

Tags: php, html, facebook

mi problema es el siguiente:
Agregué un botón compartir de Facebook, a mi página. Pero al momento de hacerlo no me aparece correctamente la noticia. Me aparece sin imagen.

He usado el depurador de contenido de Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) para ver como se visualiza hasta que logré poner todas las etiquetas necesarias. og:url, og:type, og:image, etc...

EL problema es que cuando use el depurador de contenido de Facebook lo use con la noticia de ejemplo **miweb.com/noticias.php?id=3** y al COMPARTIR es la única que me aparece correctamente.

Si abro la noticia **miweb.com/noticias.php?id=2** por ejemplo y al darle al botón COMPARTIR. Me aparece el título, la descripción PERO NO APARECE LA IMAGEN de la noticia 2

Como puedo hacer para que cualquier noticia a medida que vaya agregando, se puedan ver correctamente? Debería ser automático, ya que es el mismo codigo, lo único que cambia es el ID de la noticia.
Espero que se entienda mi problema o duda.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Creo que como cada noticia provee una img y unos textos diferentes debes usar el depurador con cada una, no estoy seguro.

Comment: Gracias @CamiloVasquez por responder, yo dudo mucho que sea así, porque te volverías loco si vas subiendo muchas noticias. No es mi caso, pero yo creo que es algo automatico, solo que quizas algo estoy pasando por alto.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón no debería de ser así, yo también he sufrido mucho con ese depurador :c